# Get second string from array

Tags: c++, c

I'm using a char array:

```
char *strs[3] = {"foo", "bar", "bletch"};
LCDPutStr(*strs, 17);
```

The output is `foo`. How can I select another item? e.g `bar` or `bletch` from array.

Comment: Note that this is ill formed in c++ (since c++11) because string literals (in c++) are const and your pointers are not.

Comment: @chux ... should I just not lefting a comment at all? Probably in this case it's better...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strs` is an array of `char *`.  Arrays in C have a starting index of 0 are indexed with `[]`.

So if you want the second element you would use `strs[1]`.

Comment: Thank you sir it was so easy!

Comment: @dim Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to explain it for dummys.

`strs` is an array of `strings`.Without `&` or the `sizeof` operator `strs` converts to a pointer to the first element of the array.The first element is a pointer to a string(all elements are).Imagine `strs` becoming a double pointer.Now you have a double pointer pointing to a pointer to a string.When you dereference `strs` you get the address of the string.`strs+1` will point to the second element.A side note:i see a lot of new C programmers doing this mistake `strs++`.You can't do that.

Now having that said `*strs` will get you the address of the first string.It's equivalent to `*(strs+0)` and `strs[0]`.Interesting thing to mention is that `*(strs+0)` is equivalent to `*(0+strs)` which makes `0[strs]`also possible.

Dereferencing it once more will give you the letters of the strings.For example `strs[0][0]` will give you `'f'`.It's equivalent to `**strs`and `*(*(strs+0)+0)`.